# Handle GPIO in Kernel and User Space ARM9 Embedded Linux AM1808

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I have to handle (i.e. turn on and off) my LCD Power Pin kernel and userspace both side.

We have configured the gpio pin in Mux.h,da850.c and board-da850-evm.c properly.

The problem is that when we configure this pin in kernel then this pin is not access by /sys/class/gpio.

We have configured this in in board-da850-evm.c as below,

```
ret = gpio_request(DA850_LCD_GP3, "LCD GP3");

if (ret)

pr_warning("Cannot open GPIO %d\n", DA850_LCD_GP3);

gpio_direction_output(DA850_LCD_GP3, 1);

gpio_set_value(DA850_LCD_GP3,1);
```

If we comment this section.and export from userspace then we used this pin form userspace successfully.

Is it possible to handle gpio form kernel and userspace?
Or do we need to write the gpio drive ?

Comment: In kernel, why not just describe it in device tree file as `reset-gpios` property? See `Documentation/devicetree/bindings/display/panel/panel-dsi-cm.txt` for details. In user-space, see `/sys/class/gpio/*` files. You can add your gpio there using `export` file.

Comment: Once a driver acquires a GPIO, then that pin is no longer available through sysfs.  It's a resource (like memory); it cannot be allocated more than once.  Only unused pins are available through /sys/class/gpio.  I'm guessing, but there should already be an API for turning a LCD panel on/off.  I.E. you're not the first one to want this capability.

Comment: @SamProtsenko -- The doc file you mention is only available in kernel versions 4.4 and later.  You're suggesting a definition for a reset, but OP wants to control power.  Your two suggestions cannot be used together.

Comment: @sawdust You are right. I guess `enable-gpios` property would be more appropriate, but again, it all depends on which exactly panel OP's using. See `Documentation/devicetree/bindings/display/panel/simple-panel.txt` for example. But it controls only enable/disable of panel. Backlight may need to be disabled too (the same way). To handle power, I guess one should toggle corresponding regulator (`power-supply` property in LCD DT binding). For user-space control -- as I see it, driver should expose some sysfs node for this explicitly, but I doubt it does it by default.

Comment: If LCD driver doesn't support `enable-gpios` property, it should be added like this: `enable_gpio = devm_gpiod_get(&dev, "enable", GPIOD_OUT_LOW);`. See how it's implemented in 
`drivers/video/fbdev/omap2/displays-new/panel-*.c` for example. But if you need to disable panel entirely -- be sure to disable backlight as well, as it's a major power consumer and also makes your panel glow.